# Run selected text through filter and reinsert

Tags: vim

I like using code cleanup scripts; perldidy; uglifierjs, etc.  I previously ran them all like this in my vimrc...

```
map <leader>pt          :!perltidy<CR>
map <leader>jt          :!uglifyjs -b<CR>
map <leader>pjt          :!python -mjson.tool<CR>
map <leader>ct          :!column -t<CR>
```

How this functionally works; it runs currently selected text throguh the CLI program, and replaces the selection with the output.  Works wonderfully; but as you can see I now have to stop and think what beautifier I want to run and remember the nemonic I have for it.  This led me to think there has to be a better way. So I tried did this...

```
map <leader>jt :call RunTidy()<cr>
function! RunTidy()
    if (&ft == "javascript")
        echo 'is js..'
        :'<,'>!ulifyjs -b
    endif
    if (&ft == "json")
        echo 'is json'
        :'<,'>!python -mjson.tool
    endif
endfunction
```

The problem being this just doesn't work; executing once for each line and not replacing contents.. Anyone aware of a better way to do this? I feel like this should be a solved problem...

Comment: I wanted to do this recently, too, but lacked research time.  I've thought to look at the Tabular and AlignMaps plugins, to look for clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
augroup filters
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType perl       map <buffer> <leader>t :!perltidy<CR>
  autocmd FileType javascript map <buffer> <leader>t :!uglifyjs -b<CR>
  autocmd FileType json       map <buffer> <leader>t :!python -mjson.tool<CR>
augroup END
```

or put those mappings, all with the same lhs, in different `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.

Comment: Thank you. Good answers from others but this fit near directly into existing workflow in a much cleaner way than I was expecting. Knew I was approaching it wrong:)

Answer (score 2):

Use ftplugins. You need to have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc.

Create files in `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`. These files will be sourced when the file type is set.

For example using javascript put the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim`

```
noremap <buffer> <leader>jt :!uglifyjs -b<CR>
```

to map `<leader>jt` to `:!uglifyjs -b<CR>` in all javascript buffers. This will not show up in other filetypes.

You would do the same for all other filetypes.

You can do the same for file type specific settings by using `setlocal`.

Take a look at `:h ftplugin`